# How to update values with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently trying to update values from a data.frame using dplyr but I don't know if it is possible to replace a subset of values?

```
net4 <- read.table(text="
temps2 NNET NET ave
1     18    2   4  36
2     18    2   4  36
3     22    2   4  44
4     18    2   4  36
5     22    2   4  44
6     27    3   4  36", header=TRUE)

# I would like to do the same command line as below:
subs <- (net4$ave < 10 & net4$ave!=net4$temps2)
net4$ave[subs] <- with(net4[subs,], temps2/NNET*NET)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `mutate` and `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(net4,
  ave = ifelse(ave < 10 & ave != temp2, temps2 / NNET * NET, ave)
)
```